# Why does my free XCode Provisioning Profile only last 7 days?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning

I just installed the last version of XCode to test my app on my iPad Pro 9.7 on iOS 9.3, but each time I create a free provisioning profile with the "Fix Issue" option my profile is valid only 7 days.

Free profiles are valid 90 days right? So why just 7 days for me?

Comment: Ok found it, Apple just reduced 90 days to 7 days for free accounts...

Answer (score 4):

Apple has reduced the time-to-live for the free provisioning profiles from 90 days to 7 days.

And there's another limit that now you can only generate 10 app IDs within one week.

But you can get a developer's account for 99$ year, then your provisioning profile can last 1 year. :)